# How to understand correctly scope of local variable in LaTeX3?

Tags: latex3, programming

Common programming languages (`C`).

```
// foo is global scope
int foo = 0;

int main() {
    // bar is local scope within main
    int bar = 1;
}
```

Let's consider `LaTeX3`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \create_list:n
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl {(#1)}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\uselist{m}
{
    \create_list:n {#1}
     \tl_use:N \l_my_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\uselist{2}

\end{document}
```

In `LaTeX3` I expected the scope of `\l_my_tl` is a body of `\create_list:n`. But `\l_my_tl` visible also from `\uselist{m}` macro. Why is that? What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scope in TeX, and thus in `expl3`, is not defined by macros: they are simply replaced by their definition when 'used'. Scope is therefore provided using explicit groups:

- `\group_begin:`/`\group_end:` (`expl3`) - `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` (classical TeX names)
- `{` ... `}` or `\bgroup`/`\egroup`

The brace-based version potentially impacts on math mode spacing, and in `expl3` we always use the first type of grouping.

---

There are some 'hidden' scopes, such as table cells, but for the bulk of programming these are not what we use.